# Replace a specific line in a text file using an array Swift 5 Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, swift, text-files

I'm converting my app from Java Android to Swift 5 iOS.

I cannot seem to find anything that points to what I am looking for.

Essentially I have an array that I load my file into. I use this in order to access the specific line that needs to be replaced. The only thing I cannot seem to get is to load the array back to the file. (essentially replacing the contents of the file with the contents of the array).

I understand I may need to do something to convert the array back but unsure if this is the best method.

```
func saveToFile(bagged: Int, iD: Int, dateBagged: Date){
        var arrayOfLines: [String]?

        let dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter();
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat;

        let dateBaggedFormatted = dateFormatter.string(from: dateBagged)

        do {
            let file = "file.txt"

            if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

                let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

                let data = try String(contentsOf:fileURL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

                arrayOfLineStrings = data.components(separatedBy: "\r\n")


                for i in 0 ..< arrayOfLines!.count {
                    let attributes: [String] =  arrayOfLines![i].components(separatedBy: ",");
                    if (attributes[0] == String(iD)) {
                        let replaceLine: String = attributes[0] + "," +
                            attributes[1] + "," +
                            attributes[2] + "," +
                            attributes[3] + "," +
                            attributes[4] + "," +
                            attributes[5] + "," +
                            String(bagged) + "," +
                        dateBaggedFormatted;
                        arrayOfLines![i]=replaceLine
                        break;
                    }
                }

//                let contents = try! String(contentsOf: fileURL)
//                let lines = contents.split(separator:"\r\n")
//                
//                for line in lines {
//                    try line.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
//                }
            }
        }
        catch {/* error handling here */}
    }
```

I achieved this in Java with:

```
Files.write(Paths.get(outFile.getAbsolutePath()), fileContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); (I understand that will probably not help at all...)
```

If further information is required. Let me know

Comment: Unclear what it would mean to write an array of lines. Basically you should _join_ the array of lines to form a string; now you just write the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use a more efficient way to find the line starting with `iD plus comma`. And according to the code the 7th field is `bagged` and the 8th field is `baggedDate`.

So write the changes directly into the `attributes` array, rejoin it, reassign the string to the `lines` array at given index and join the `lines` array with CRLF separator. Finally write the string back to disk

```
func saveToFile(bagged: Int, iD: Int, dateBagged: Date){
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"

    let dateBaggedFormatted = dateFormatter.string(from: dateBagged)

    do {
        let file = "file.txt"

        let dir = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

        let text = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
        var lines = text.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
        if let index = lines.firstIndex(where: {$0.hasPrefix("\(iD),")}) {
            var attributes = lines[index].components(separatedBy: ",")
            attributes[6] = String(bagged)
            attributes[7] = dateBaggedFormatted
            lines[index] = attributes.joined(separator: ",")
            let result = lines.joined(separator: "\r\n")
            try result.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        }
    } catch {print(error)}
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate this cleaner logic. Although it seems to be adding in an extra empty string after each line. I will work on trying to remove it!

Comment: I have changed separatedBy: .newlines to  separatedBy: "\r\n". This has helped me greatly. Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 2):

As you've been told, the way to write a string to a file is

```
try? myString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
```

So if `arrayOfLines` is a `[String]`, you can say

```
try? arrayOfLines.joined(separator: "\n").write(to:...)
```

Comment: Ninja'd by over two minutes! One slight thing though: he separated by `"\r\n"` so that's probably the exact thing to join on.

Comment: Like I stated if any clarification needed I'm happy to add. I found the joined method after posting and really appreciate your answer. Thanks for the help. This community seems to be more harsh when answering questions...

Comment: @Tommy totally. Your comment helped me remember to add that!