# iOS Swift replace or update specific line in a file using file handle?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, point-clouds

I am writing a point cloud file and need to keep updating the file header with the total number of points in a file: `vertexCount`. I don't know when the points will stop coming, so I can not just keep accumulating the values and waiting to write it to file.

The `vertexCount` value is kept on line 3 of ascii file, which is newline terminated.

I only see examples and functions that append data to the end of the file using `write(to: URL, options: .atomic)`

**How can I use FileHandle to replace a specific line in a file, or overwrite the entire header?**

```
   ply
   format ascii 1.0
   element vertex \(vertexCount)
```

I see [this question about replacing file contents using an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60422698/replace-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file-using-an-array-swift-5-xcode-ios). Due to the file having at least 400 thousand lines, I do not want to separate it into individual lines. I was thinking of separating it on the end_header keyword, and then generating a new header, but am not sure how efficient this is.

Comment: Well the issue you will face is that when the numbers of digits increase it will overwrite the characters after it. You will need to use a fixed numbers of digits to be able to write them exactly over it (something like 0000001). The number of lines doesn't really matter because it will replace any new line character after the last digit

Comment: Another option is to leave some spaces before the new line to allow the number of digits to increase and you will gradually reduce the space between the count and the new line character.

Comment: Yes, the number of digits could be a problem. I'm not sure how different systems parse integers, but I think 0000001 is a valid integer. Worst case scenario, the user can just trim the extra zeroes by hand, if some system does not accept this ascii file. Still don't know if FileHandle can do what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Check my post below

Comment: @LeoDabus Will check out your solution. If I want to export everything in one file, the digit count is 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue you will face is that when the numbers of digits increase it will overwrite the characters after it. You will need to use a fixed numbers of digits to be able to write them exactly over it (something like 0000000001). The number of lines doesn't really matter because it will replace any new line character after the last digit.

```
extension FixedWidthInteger where Self: CVarArg {
    func strZero(maxLength: Int) -> String {
        String(format: "%0*d", maxLength, self)
    }

    func write(toPLYFile atURL: URL) throws {
        let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forUpdating: atURL)
        try fileHandle.seek(toOffset: 36)
        try fileHandle.write(contentsOf: Data(strZero(maxLength: 10).utf8))
        fileHandle.closeFile()
    }
}

var vertexCount = 1
let text = """
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex \(vertexCount.strZero(maxLength: 10))
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
1234567890
"""
print(text)
print("=========")
let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    .appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
try Data(text.utf8).write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forUpdating: fileURL)
try fileHandle.seek(toOffset: 36)
vertexCount = 12345
try fileHandle.write(contentsOf: Data(vertexCount.strZero(maxLength: 10).utf8))
fileHandle.closeFile()
let stringLoaded = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
print(stringLoaded)
```

---

This will print

> ply
> format ascii 1.0
> element vertex 0000000001
> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
> 1234567890
> =========
> ply
> format ascii 1.0
> element vertex 0000012345
> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
> 1234567890

---

**Updated use:**

```
do {
    // filepath to PLY file that is being updated
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) 
    
    let totalVertexCount = 12345
    try totalVertexCount.write(toPLYFile: url)
} catch {
    print("Error writing PLY! \(error)")
    return
}
```

Comment: Thank, this looks exactly like what I was trying to find out!

Comment: @AlexStone Not sure why are you still using paths but you should definitely avoid it.

Comment: It's a string, stored to core data. I have not experimented with archiving/unarchiving URLs yet.

Comment: Just make sure to do not store the whole path. You should store only the file name and its location (directory)

Comment: in other words the application is sandboxed so the path (location) will change each time the user launches it. So you need to reconstruct the url using only the file name (and subdirectory is needed)

Comment: Very interesting, I will need to test my file storage in more detail, as I implement the document-based app approach (so I can view my own files in the Apple's provided file browser)

Answer (score 1):

This is just something I've written really quick, definitely look into making it look and work a bit better - but should be enough to demonstrate the concept. Needs some testing to see if this is actually more efficient than separating line by line.

What it's essentially doing is it's reading the file byte by byte into an array until it finds the beginning of the third line. Then, it copies our new string into the buffer. After that, it's looking for the beginning of the fourth line and copying the rest of the file into the buffer.

I'm also calculating the total byte size so that I can trim the buffer at the end.

```
var finalFileByteLength = 0;

if let d = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
    
    let newLine = "element vertex \(vertexCount)\n".data(using: .ascii)! as NSData
    var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: d.length + newLine.length)
    
    var bytePosition = 0
    var lineCount = 0
    while(true) {
        //Read one Byte
        d.getBytes(&buffer+bytePosition, range: NSMakeRange(bytePosition, 1))
        
        //If it's a new line character
        if(buffer[bytePosition] == 10) {
            lineCount += 1
            //If it found the end of the second line, copy our new line
            if lineCount == 2 {
                newLine.getBytes(&buffer+(bytePosition+1), length: newLine.length)
                bytePosition += 1
                break
            }
        }
        
        bytePosition += 1
        finalFileByteLength+=1
    }
    
    var oldLine3Length = 0
    finalFileByteLength+=newLine.length
    
    //Find the start of the fourth line in the initial file
    while(true) {
        //Read one Byte
        var char = UInt8()
        d.getBytes(&char, range: NSMakeRange(bytePosition, 1))
        
        //If it's a new line character
        if(char == 10) {
            //If it found the end of the third line, break so we have the start of the fourth line
            bytePosition += 1
            oldLine3Length += 1
            break
        }
        
        bytePosition += 1
        oldLine3Length += 1
    }
    
    //Header is now modified, copy the rest of the file
    d.getBytes(&buffer+(bytePosition+newLine.length-oldLine3Length), range: NSMakeRange(bytePosition, d.length - bytePosition))
    finalFileByteLength+=d.length - bytePosition + 1
    
    let finalFileData = NSData(bytes: &buffer, length: finalFileByteLength)
    
    //Print the result - this is probably where you'll write the entire String to a file
    print(String(data: finalFileData as Data, encoding: .ascii))
}
```

EDIT: Managed to reduce to this:

```
if let d = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
    
    let newLine = "element vertex \(vertexCount)".data(using: .ascii)! as NSData
    var newLineBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: newLine.length)
    newLine.getBytes(&newLineBuffer, length: newLine.length)
    
    var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: d.length)
    d.getBytes(&buffer, length: d.length)
    
    var thirdIndex = buffer.firstIndex(of: 10)
    thirdIndex = buffer[buffer.index(after: thirdIndex!)...].firstIndex(of: 10)
    thirdIndex = buffer[buffer.index(after: thirdIndex!)...].firstIndex(of: 10)
    var fourthIndex = buffer[buffer.index(after: thirdIndex!)...].firstIndex(of: 10)
    
    buffer.removeSubrange(thirdIndex!+1..<fourthIndex!)
    buffer.insert(contentsOf: newLineBuffer, at: thirdIndex!+1)
    
    let finalFileData = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: buffer.count) as Data
    print(String(data:finalFileData, encoding: .ascii))
}
```

Comment: This is loading the whole file to memory (400 thousand lines) and it is not updating/writing just the vertexCount

Comment: Yeah, the solutions around splitting the file would work, but 400 thousand is already a compromise. The full file may have 20 million lines. While the split solution may be a short term stop gap, I'm interested if there's a better, in-place write solution.